# Bing Map Search by Id

Tags: c#, bing-maps, bing-api

When doing a Bing search using the SOAP API, the results that are returned have an Id associated with them.

Is there a way to do a search and get back the single record by it's Id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. There is no option for this.

Also, for anyone else who comes across this thread. The Bing Maps SOAP services are really old and the Bing Maps team stopped recommending them 4 years ago when the better, faster Bing Maps REST services were released.